VWP for residents of non-VWP countries
This is kind of a follow-up to someone else's question, Can I enter the US with my still valid ESTA and B2 visa application after moving to Mexico?, where they stated:

Now an officer told me that I need a B2 visa since I moved my residency from Belgium to Mexico

I found this interesting/odd/unusual at the time, and answered that question with my experience of being a citizen of a Visa Waiver Program (VWP) country now residing in Mexico (a non-VWP country).
However, since then I have overheard, on at least two occasions, a CBP officer say something along the same lines as above, that being a resident of a non-VWP country means that a visa is required.
Earlier this week my wife and I crossed the land border from Tijuana into San Diego, and presented our SENTRI cards and passports as normal.  The CBP officer was being trained by another, who asked us if we lived in Mexico (we do), and then went on to tell the trainee officer something along the lines of:

Because they are now residents of a non-VWP country they are unable to enter under the VWP and that's why they have B1/B2 visas

So now I am wondering, is this an actual policy/requirement that they don't really enforce, or are we just encountering many misinformed border agents?  Is there documentation online to show this one way or the other?

As to the incident at the border, do you in fact have a B1/B2 visa? If so, may I ask why? If not, did they let you in anyway?

@NateEldredge Yes we have B1/B2 visas.  We were advised to get them by CBP back in 2017 (along the same lines as above).  When I wrote my answer to the above linked question I mentioned this and that it was incorrect advice (at least that's what I thought, but now I'm having doubts).  I have friends living here that have used VWP seemingly without issue for years though, so it's unusual.

All the CBP, DoS, and DHS public documentation mentions no residency conditions. I've never heard this before, this is very weird and you should maybe raise it with your VWP country foreign office.

While not needed for your target demographic it would greatly help we antipodeans learn stuff if  somewhere you mentioned what eg VWP stood for.  Volkswagpn Papers seems not to work.

@RussellMcMahon visa waiver program.

"I have friends living here that have used VWP seemingly without issue for years though": at the same port of entry?  If not, are they flying or crossing the land border at a different point?

@phoog yes, at the same ports of entry

If there is such a requirement, it is well hidden.
The Visa Waiver Program is defined by:

Section 217 of the Immigration and Nationality Act (INA 217 aka 8 USC 1187)
8 CFR part 217

The only reference to residence I found in there is in 8 CFR 217.2(c)(1):

Applicants arriving by air and sea.  Applicants must arrive on a carrier that is signatory to a Visa Waiver Program Agreement and at the time of arrival must have a round trip ticket that will transport the traveler out of the United States to any other foreign port or place as long as the trip does not terminate in contiguous territory or an adjacent island; except that the round trip ticket may transport the traveler to contiguous territory or an adjacent island, if the traveler is a resident of the country of destination.

So if you are not a resident of Mexico, you cannot arrive by air or sea with a ticket to Mexico as proof of onward travel, but you can use that if you are a resident of Mexico (which proves you can use VWP while being a resident of Mexico).
The Foreign Affairs Manual says the same thing.
The latter also lists exemptions for Mexican nationals, and a weird story about some Canadian residents, but there's no mention of Mexican residents.
The Department of state also tells us:

Citizens of VWP countries* who reside in Mexico, Canada, or a nearby island are generally exempted from the requirement to show onward travel to another country* when entering the United States

Which makes it clear again that the VWP applies even for residents of Mexico, since they are entitled to exemptions!
So no, there is no requirement for a visa for (eligible) citizens of VWP countries, regardless of their country of residence. Eligibility for the VWP (in terms of countries) is based solely on citizenship, not residence.
Some CBP agent probably must have misunderstood a rule somewhere ("there is an exception for residents of Mexico" -- sure, there is, but the exception is not that they can't use the VWP, but rather that they don't need to prove they're exiting US+MX+CA+islands like the others when arriving by air or sea). And they are repeating it to trainees!
NB: I believe that along the same lines, there is also an exception to the "readmit on same I-94" when travelling to/from a country one is resident of. So yet another exception, but not to VWP eligibility, but rather to how I-94s can/need to be processed.
NB2: Of course one issue they may have (or may be confusing things with) is that some people may officially reside in Mexico but come work in the US every day, or somehow spend a lot of time in the US. But then they wouldn't need a B-1/B-2 visa but some other kind of visa to be allowed to work or stay a lot more than a "real visitor" would.

I found it also in an other ESTA page (sort of FAQ), definitely hidden. I wonder what else we may have missed. So thank you for the question: it made us aware of some corner cases.

@GiacomoCatenazzi what did you find in another ESTA page?

@phoog: the same exception about contiguous states and residency. Really hidden: not on main pages or the two main FAQ

Thanks - certainly does seem like it's just repeated misunderstanding, hopefully not becoming an issue

@GiacomoCatenazzi but what "same" exception?  There are a few exceptions under discussion, some of which are well documented and one of which seems to be a figment of some CBP officer's imagination (e.g. the exception to the "round trip ticket" definition vs. the purported VWP ineligibility as the CBP officers are claiming).  If you found an official statement of the purported VWP ineligibility exception online then please provide the link.

@phoog: my comment was about exceptions being hidden (and not on main FAQs). The answer say "the only reference". I just found an other one, but still it remain very hidden. It is not about new cases (I would write an answer on such case)


now I am wondering, is this an actual policy/requirement that they don't really enforce,

No, it is not.

or are we just encountering many misinformed border agents?

It seems that you are.

Is there documentation online to show this one way or the other?

As jcaron notes in his answer, there are regulatory provisions that apply to VWP travelers who reside in "contiguous territory or an adjacent island" -- where "adjacent territory" means "Canada and Mexico," neither of which is a VWP country.
So, as mentioned, it seems that the CBP officers you've encountered do not in fact understand the laws and regulations governing the VWP.  There are several points of immigration law that officers of CBP (and other DHS agencies) do not understand correctly.
Whether this particular misunderstanding arose and spread through rumors or was promulgated officially by the department, I do not know.  My sense is that individual CBP offices have somewhat distinct cultures.  My guess is that if you asked this question of a CBP officer at JFK (or perhaps any airport) they would say "of course you can use the VWP."
It's also possible that the idea that you need a visa is related to the "readmission from contiguous territory" rule or the "round-trip ticket" rule, whether because of a misunderstanding or because of some other line of reasoning.
If you want to pursue this, you could perhaps make an official complaint and/or write to the Office of the Chief Counsel, which is charged in part with providing legal guidance to CBP officers in the performance of their duties.  The goal would be to get CBP to retrain the officers or at least to send a policy memo reminding them that VWP eligibility does not depend on residence.

Thanks - I'm not sure if I can be bothered making a complaint since it doesn't really affect us anyway, but will see if it starts becoming more of an issue for others.

@Midavalo I wouldn't have thought so, since you already have the B visa.  And even if it's not required, it may indeed make frequent crossings simpler, as I believe you've mentioned in the past.  But I can imagine that someone at some point will be sufficiently motivated to pursue it.
